# Setting scrollbar of a tabpage to the top

Tags: c#, scrollbar, tabpage

I searched around the internet and didn't found a solution till now, so I will ask here. 
I have a simple scrollbar in my tabpage (of a TabControl). Now when I open the form, the scrollbar somehow is not at the very top of the form. It's a little bit moved. I just want the scrollbar to be at the top when the tabpage is selected the first time. I tried:

```
tabPage1.AutoScrollPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
```

and

```
tabPage1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
tabPage1.PerformLayout();
```

but nothing of these examples work. What did work is this code:

```
tabPage1.Paint += (sender, args) => { tabPage1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0; };
```

This moves the scrollbar to the very top of the tabpage but it can not be moved anymore because the event gets triggered everytime one tries to scroll and sets the scrollbar back to the top immediately.

Can someone help?

EDIT:
I have a ToolStrip on the top of my tabPage. The scrollbar starts directly after the ToolStrip.

Comment: Have you set tabPage1.AutoScroll = true?

Comment: Yes I have. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set:

```
TabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
```

And then:

```
TabPage1.ScrollIntoView(Control FirstItemOfTabPage);
```

Or maybe the code you already tried works when you add TabPage1.AutoScroll = true.

I hope it works!

EDIT:
I just found this:

```
tabpage1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(-tabpage1.AutoScrollPosition.Y, 0)
```

Maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: The example below does not work even after modification and for the example abve: FirstItemOfTabPage can not be found.

Comment: Of course you have to get the first item of the tabpage first and store it in a variable. then use TabPage1.ScrollItemIntoView(Variable)

Comment: Still does not work :( I have a toolStrip at the top. Only half of it gets shown. even when I try this it stays like it was. - Is it somehow possible to modify the example I posted above (the event handler) so that it gets just fired once at the start?

Comment: hmm..  that's weird... maybe you can post a bit more of the code you're using so i can see what's going on.

Comment: After the InitializeComponent() I just have this: tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem); - but thats it. Don't know if this has something to do with that.

Comment: No solution for this?